# SEAM @DataModelSelection scope

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, seam

Suppouse I have a `dataTable`, with one of it's columns being a `commandLink`, which opens a `rich:modalPanel` with detailed info about the item. The question is, whether the @DataModelSelection field will still have the row on which I clicked on the commandLink when the modalPanel is open? Currently I try to show one of items' fields with simple outputText and it's not rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, reading the [following](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/java/jboss/seam/displaying-and-rerendering-a-richfaces-modalpanel-from-a-commandlink.html) article helped.